# Could not load file or assembly in .net core

Tags: .net, iis, .net-assembly

I'm coding a project with .net core, if i build and run at visual studio work fine but when i create an application inside a site in IIS the server error is:

Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLdvD.png)

The problem here is that CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine in project version it 13.0.4003, but the compilator of IIS try load at version 10.2.3600, the question is, Where is the file that IIS found to compilate an assembly? in this file can i edit at version to be equals at the project?

Thanks!!

- I tried change all versions to package to version 13.0.4003, but don't work
- search in all project that contain a line with version 10.2.3600, but not found files with this line.

Comment: Please make sure to explicitly add a reference to it in your bin folder, right click on bin folder, add reference , and select `CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine`.